# php how to replace data from one class to another

Tags: php

Hi I have a checkout page, and a user can store multiple addresses on their account. On the checkout page it will show the primary address. I would like to be able to allow the user to choose from the list off addresses and change the information for where the primary address would be. How can i achieve this?

```
//SHOW PRIMARY ADDRESS FROM DB set by user

// $myid is users id from DB

<?php

$primaryaddsql = "SELECT * FROM cust_address WHERE cust_ID = '$myid' AND primary_add = '1'";
$primaryadd = mysqli_query($conn,$primaryaddsql); 
$mainaddress = mysqli_fetch_assoc($primaryadd)

echo'
<div class="mainAdd" >
<p class="thisadd">'.$mainaddress['address_1'].'</p>
<p class="thisadd">'.$mainaddress['address_2'].'</p>
<p class="thisadd">'.$mainaddress['city'].'</p>
<p class="thisadd">'.$mainaddress['country'].'</p>
<p class="thisadd">'.$mainaddress['post_code'].'</p>';  
 ?>


//SHOW ALL ADDRESSES FROM DB FOR USER TO CHOOSE FROM

 <?php
 $myaddsql = "SELECT * FROM cust_address WHERE cust_ID = '$myid' AND primary_add != '1' ";
 $myaddresults = mysqli_query($conn,$myaddsql);
while($myrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($myaddresults)){
echo '

                            <div class="myleft" data-id="'.$myrow['address_ID'].'">
                             <p class="thisadd" >'.$myrow['address_1'].'</p>
                             <p class="thisadd">'.$myrow['address_2'].'</p>
                             <p class="thisadd">'.$myrow['city'].'</p>
                             <p class="thisadd">'.$myrow['country'].'</p>
                             <p class="thisadd">'.$myrow['post_code'].'</p>
                         </div>

                         ';
                }              
            ?>
```

Comment: So you want `<select>` HTML element.

Comment: There are lots of different ways of achieving this, with lots of different parts that you may or may not already know, so it would be hard to give a single definitive answer, meaning this doesn't really fit the format of this site. If you can narrow down what you're trying to do, and make an attempt yourself, feel free to ask a more specific question about where you got stuck.

Comment: hi thanks for the response, could you please give me an idea on how you would achieve it, in the most simplest form